# Can't start Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jdk

So I've been having some problems lately with Android Studio (Gradle not syncing, can't target JDK, etc..). So I completely uninstalled and reinstalled both Android Studio and JDK. But now when I try to launch it the splash screen loads then I'm greeted with this message

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:212)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:380)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:257)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:501)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:437)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:444)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:90)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:396)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:382)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:205)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:157)
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:76)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:82)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.<init>(AndroidSdkData.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getSdkData(AndroidSdkData.java:104)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getSdkData(AndroidSdkData.java:78)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getSdkData(AndroidSdkData.java:112)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getSdkData(AndroidSdkData.java:119)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.parse(AndroidPlatform.java:86)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:137)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.getInstance(AndroidPlatform.java:68)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getEligibleAndroidSdks(IdeSdks.java:591)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getFirstAndroidSdk(IdeSdks.java:191)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:117)
at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.setupSdks(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:283)
at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.run(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:116)
at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:206)
at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:72)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:459)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.3.2.1] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@e5e4d0b
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 54 more
```

**Note**: I have JDK 11.0.1 installed and IntelliJ IDEA along Android Studio

Comment: Are you 100% positive that Android Studio supports JDK 11?  What version of the JDK did you have installed when it was working?  Edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: I don't know. Before I reinstalled all was going good until just all of a sudden I had gradle sync issues, is it possible that the JDK auto updated from version 8 to 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by reinstalling Android Studio. I don't really know what caused the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

[Android Studio is not compatible with Java 11.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46402772/1038828) You'll need to install Java 8 and use JDK 8 instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to install JDK 8 and update you with tbe details.